# Javascript how to properly filter html divs

Tags: javascript, html, web, filter, audio-player

So I’ve been creating an html music player, and I’ve run into a problem. The problem is that when I click on an album, it filters out all the song that belong to any album, instead of filtering out the songs that only belong to the clicked album. Here is my .js files.

**main.js**

```
var btnv = 0;
var update = 0;
var NumberOfSongs = 37;
function Dropdown() {
var i = 0;
if (i == 0) {
i++;
document.getElementById("Dropbutton").classList.toggle("dropbtnclick");
document.getElementById("Dropbutton").classList.toggle("dropbtnpos");
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  document.getElementById("PlaylistDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  document.getElementById("SearchBox").setAttribute("style", "height: 30px;");
} else {
i--;
document.getElementById("Dropbutton").classList.remove("dropbtnclick");
}}

window.onerror = function(error) {console.log(error);};

function startUI() {    
  var SB;    
    for (SB = 0; SB < NumberOfSongs;) {
    SB++;
        let NewSongBtn = document.createElement("a");
        NewSongBtn.id = SB;
        NewSongBtn.setAttribute("style", "color: white; padding: 10px 50px; text-decoration: none; text-align: left; display: block; border-top: 0.9px solid #9B9898;");     
        NewSongBtn.innerHTML = titles[SB] + " -- " + artists[SB];
        NewSongBtn.onclick = function() {Playbutton(NewSongBtn.id);};
        let LI = document.createElement("li");
        LI.appendChild(NewSongBtn);
        document.getElementById("SongBtns").appendChild(LI);
    }
    var n;
    for (n = 0; n < NumberOfSongs; n++) {}
    createAlbums();
}

function createAlbums() {    
  var AB;    
  for (AB = 0; AB < NumberOfSongs;) {
  AB++;
    if (AlbumName[AB] == "") {} else {
      if (AlbumIMG[AB] == "") {} else {
        let NewAlbumBtn = document.createElement("div");                
        NewAlbumBtn.classList.toggle("column");
        NewAlbumBtn.id = AB;
        NewAlbumBtn.setAttribute("style", "float: left; width: 25%; padding: 0 8px; text-align:center;align-items:center; display: inline-block; float: none;  white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;");     
        //NewAlbumBtn.innerHTML = AlbumName[AB];
        NewAlbumBtn.onclick = function() {PlayAlbum(NewAlbumBtn.id);};
        let IMG = document.createElement("img");
        IMG.src = AlbumIMG[AB];
        IMG.style.width = "100%";
        NewAlbumBtn.appendChild(IMG);
        let text = document.createElement("p");
        text.innerHTML = AlbumName[AB];
        NewAlbumBtn.appendChild(text);
        document.getElementById("albums").appendChild(NewAlbumBtn);
}}}}

function PlayAlbum(clicked_id) {
  Id = clicked_id;
  var AN;
  for (AN = 0; AN < NumberOfSongs;) {
    AN++;
    let AB = document.getElementById(AN);
    if (AlbumName[AB.id] == AlbumName[Id]) {      
      console.log("AlbumName " + AlbumName[Id]);
    } else {                           
        console.log("id: " + Id.id + " AB " + AB.id);
        AB.remove();
    }  
  }
}

function Update() {  
  let UpdateContainer = document.createElement("div");
  UpdateContainer.id = "UC";
  UpdateContainer.classList.toggle("NewUpdate");
  document.body.appendChild(UpdateContainer);

  let Updatetxt = document.createElement("div");
  Updatetxt.id = "UTXT";
  var wm = "Welcome to LanyxSoft Music!";
  var wmr= wm.bold();
  Updatetxt.innerHTML = wmr + " please note that this web player is still in beta testing mode meaning that there will most likely be issues. Thank you for you coaperation.";
  Updatetxt.setAttribute("style", "z-index: 7; position: fixed; left: 50%; top: 15%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); text-align: center; color: black; font-size: 20px; width: 430px;")
  UpdateContainer.appendChild(Updatetxt);

  let Updatebackground = document.createElement("div");
  Updatebackground.id = "UB";
  Updatebackground.classList.toggle("UpdateBackground");
  document.body.appendChild(Updatebackground);

  let UpdateScrollController = document.createElement("div");
  UpdateScrollController.setAttribute("style", "z-index: 7; position: fixed; left: 50%; top: 40%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); text-align: left; color: black; font-size: 20px; width: 430px; height: 120px;")
  UpdateScrollController.id = "USC";
  UpdateContainer.appendChild(UpdateScrollController);  

  let UpdateHead = document.createElement("div");
  UpdateHead.id = "UH";
  var u = "UPDATES";
  var ur = u.bold();
  UpdateHead.innerHTML = ur;
  UpdateHead.setAttribute("style", "position: relative; text-align: center; color: black; font-size: 23px; width: 430px;")
  UpdateScrollController.appendChild(UpdateHead);

  let Updatetxt2 = document.createElement("div");
  Updatetxt2.id = "UTXT2";
  var UTXT2B = "Automatic button creation";  
  Updatetxt2.innerHTML = UTXT2B.bold() + " makes the player's ability to load faster.";
  Updatetxt2.setAttribute("style", "position: relative; text-align: left; color: black; font-size: 20px; width: 430px;")
  UpdateScrollController.appendChild(Updatetxt2);

  let Updatetxt3 = document.createElement("div");
  Updatetxt3.id = "UTXT3";
  var UTXT3B = "Automatic Update notifications";  
  Updatetxt3.innerHTML = UTXT3B.bold() + " makes sure that when there's a new update, you will be notified.";
  Updatetxt3.setAttribute("style", "position: relative; text-align: left; color: black; font-size: 20px; width: 430px;")
  UpdateScrollController.appendChild(Updatetxt3);

  let Updatetxt4 = document.createElement("div");
  Updatetxt4.id = "UTXT4";
  var UTXT4B = "More Album Art";  
  Updatetxt4.innerHTML = UTXT4B.bold() + " new and updated album art.";
  Updatetxt4.setAttribute("style", "position: relative; text-align: left; color: black; font-size: 20px; width: 430px;")
  UpdateScrollController.appendChild(Updatetxt4);

  let Updatebutton = document.createElement("div");
  Updatebutton.id = "UBTN";
  Updatebutton.classList.toggle("UpdateCB");
  Updatebutton.style.fontSize = "xx-large";
  Updatebutton.innerHTML = "Continue";
  Updatebutton.onclick = function() {document.getElementById("UTXT").style.visibility = "hidden"; document.getElementById("UTXT2").style.visibility = "hidden"; document.getElementById("UC").style.visibility = "hidden"; document.getElementById("UB").style.visibility = "hidden"; document.getElementById("UBTN").style.visibility = "hidden"; startUI();}
  UpdateContainer.appendChild(Updatebutton);  
}

var config = {apiKey:"", authDomain: "”, databaseURL: "", projectId: "", storageBucket: "", messagingSenderId: ""};  
firebase.initializeApp(config);  
function InitializeStartzup() {
  let id = localStorage.getItem("LUDIN");
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('LanyxSoft-Music-Update/' + id + '/updatestats');
  ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    startUI();
  });
}
function BeginUpdate() {    
    var postData = {};
    let id = (0|Math.random()*9e6).toString(36)+"-"+(0|Math.random()*9e6).toString(36)+"-"+(0|Math.random()*9e6).toString(36);    
    var updates = {};
    let L = localStorage.getItem("LUDIN");
    Update();
    firebase.database().ref('LanyxSoft-Music-Update/' + L).set({
      updated : "true"
    });

    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/LanyxSoft-Music-Update/'+id);
      ref.on("child_added", function(child) {
            var IDofFriends = child.val();
                if(IDofFriends == localStorage.getItem("LUDIN")) {                  
                    console.log("func: child_added result: User id matches to id in accepted LanyxSoft database");
                } else {
                    console.log("func: child_added result: User id  doesn't match to id in accepted LanyxSoft database");
                }
      });  

    //updates["/posts/" + "hihihihihi"] = postData;
    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
  }
//child_added

function SetID() {
  let id = (0|Math.random()*9e6).toString(36)+"-"+(0|Math.random()*9e6).toString(36)+"-"+(0|Math.random()*9e6).toString(36);    
  localStorage.setItem("LUDIN", id); 
  BeginUpdate();              
}
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  if (localStorage.getItem("LUDIN") == null) { 
    console.log("func: SetID() result:", true);
    SetID();    
  } else {
    console.log("func: InitializeStartzup() result:", true); //console.log("func: InitializeStartzup() result: func success= "+ true);
    InitializeStartzup();              
  }
} else {  
  Update();
  console.log("s means that some feature aren't available on this device");
}

function drop() {

}

window.onclick = function(event, clicked_id) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        //openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
       }}}}

//labels

//buttons
var input = document.getElementById("button");
var input2 = document.getElementById("button2");
//text/labels/numbers
  //number vals
var num = 1;
var a = new Date();
var mt = a.getMonth() + 1;
var dy = a.getDate();
var yr = a.getFullYear();
var tm = a.getHours()+":"+a.getMinutes();
var dateFormat = mt+"/"+dy+"/"+yr+"_"+tm;
  //labels
var audiotitle = document.getElementById("audiotitle");
var audioartist = document.getElementById("artist");
var image = document.getElementById("AlbumArt");
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 
var percent = document.getElementById("currentlbl");
audiotitle.innerHTML = x.title;

//inputslider
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");

slider.oninput = function() {
  percent.innerHTML = this.value + "%";
  x.currentTime = slider.value;
}

//device orientation functions
function zoomOutMobile() {
  var viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');

  if ( viewport ) {
    viewport.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0";
  }
}

function readDeviceOrientation() {
switch (window.orientation) {  
   case 0:  
     // Portrait 
     document.getElementById("PlaylistC").style.visibility = "hidden";
     document.getElementById("PlaylistC").style.display = "none";    
     document.getElementById("container").setAttribute("style", "top: 5%; position: relative; width: 330px; min-height:480px; background: #333; overflow: auto; margin: 20px auto; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 0 10px 8px -8px #333; align-items: center; text-align: center;");                                                                                                    
     break;      
   case 180:  
     // Portrait (Upside-down)
     document.getElementById("PlaylistC").style.visibility = "hidden";
     document.getElementById("PlaylistC").style.display = "none";            
     document.getElementById("container").setAttribute("style", "top: 5%; position: relative; width: 330px; min-height:480px; background: #333; overflow: auto; margin: 20px auto; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 0 10px 8px -8px #333; align-items: center; text-align: center;");            
     break; 
   case -90:  
     // Landscape (Clockwise)         
     document.getElementById("PlaylistC").style.visibility = "visible";
     document.getElementById("PlaylistC").style.display = "block";        
     document.getElementById("container").setAttribute("style", "position: relative; width: 330px; min-height:480px; background: #333; overflow: auto; margin: 0px; left: 0; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 0 10px 8px -8px #333; align-items: center; text-align: center;");
     zoomOutMobile();             
     break;  
   case 90:  
     // Landscape  (Counterclockwise)     
     document.getElementById("PlaylistC").style.visibility = "visible";
     document.getElementById("PlaylistC").style.display = "block";             
     document.getElementById("container").setAttribute("style", "position: relative; width: 330px; min-height:480px; background: #333; overflow: auto; margin: 0px; left: 0; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 0 10px 8px -8px #333; align-items: center; text-align: center;");
     zoomOutMobile();                  
     break;
     }
 }
readDeviceOrientation();
window.onorientationchange = readDeviceOrientation;

//SEARCH
//document.getElementById("SearchBox").addEventListener("keyup",);

function search() {
  var input, filter, ui, li, a, w;
    input = document.getElementById("SearchBox");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ui = document.getElementById("PlaylistDropdown");
    li = ui.getElementsByTagName("li");

    //function for dd
    for (w = 0; w < li.length; w++) {
        a = li[w].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[w].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[w].style.display = "none";
    }}    
}
/*function searchAlbums() {
  var input, filter, ui, li, a, w;
    input = document.getElementById("SearchBox");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ui = document.getElementById("albums");
    li = ui.getElementsByTagName("div");

    //function for dd
    for (w = 0; w < li.length; w++) {
        a = li[w].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[w].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[w].style.display = "none";
    }}    
}*/


function Shuffle() {
  var s = Math.floor(Math.random() * NumberOfSongs) + 1;

  x.title = titles[s];
  audiotitle.innerHTML = x.title;
  audioartist.innerHTML = artists[s];

  if (albumart[s] == "") {
       image.src = "https://iplock.weebly.com/uploads/9/5/7/3/95731436/p164.png";
     } else {
       image.src = albumart[s];
     }

  x.src = songs[s];
  x.play();
  num = 1;
  playAudio();
}

var i = 1;
function keys() {

   if (x.currentTime == x.duration) {
     //x.src = sources.two;
     i++;
     x.title = titles[i];
     audiotitle.innerHTML = x.title;
     audioartist.innerHTML = artists[i];

     if (albumart[i] == "") {
       image.src = "https://iplock.weebly.com/uploads/9/5/7/3/95731436/p164.png";
     } else {
       image.src = albumart[i];
     }

     x.src = songs[i];
     x.play(); 
     num = 1;
     playAudio();
   }}

function next() {
     i++;
     x.title = titles[i];
     audiotitle.innerHTML = x.title;
     audioartist.innerHTML = artists[i];

     if (albumart[i] == "") {
       image.src = "https://iplock.weebly.com/uploads/9/5/7/3/95731436/p164.png";
     } else {
       image.src = albumart[i];
     }

     x.src = songs[i];
     x.play(); 
     num = 1;
     playAudio();
}

function rewind() {
     i--;
     x.title = titles[i];
     audiotitle.innerHTML = x.title;
     audioartist.innerHTML = artists[i];

     if (albumart[i] == "") {
       image.src = "https://iplock.weebly.com/uploads/9/5/7/3/95731436/p164.png";
     } else {
       image.src = albumart[i];
     }

     x.src = songs[i];
     x.play(); 
     num = 1;
     playAudio();
}

function Playbutton(clicked_id) {
  i = clicked_id;
  x.title = titles[i];
     audiotitle.innerHTML = x.title;
     audioartist.innerHTML = artists[i];

     if (albumart[i] == "") {
       image.src = "https://iplock.weebly.com/uploads/9/5/7/3/95731436/p164.png";
     } else {
       image.src = albumart[i];
     }

     x.src = songs[i];
     x.play();
     num = 1;
     playAudio();  
}


function startup() {
    input2.style.display="none";
}
startup()

function playAudio() { 
    x.play();
    if (num == 1) {
      x.play();
      //text.innerHTML = "pause";
      input.style.display="none";
      input2.style="visibility:visible;";
      input2.style.display="block";
      num = 0;
      d = dateFormat + "playing";

    } else {
      x.pause();
      //text.innerHTML = "play";
      input2.style="visibility:hidden;";
      input2.style.display="none";
      input.style="visibility:visable;";
      num = 1;
      d = dateFormat + "paused";

    }}



window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var cur = document.querySelector('#perc'),
      vid = document.querySelector('#myAudio')
      dur = document.getElementById("durationlbl");
      per = document.getElementById("currentlbl");
})

myAudio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
  //current time
  per.textContent = sToTime(e.target.currentTime);
  //duraion
  dur.textContent = sToTime(e.target.duration);
  slider.value = x.currentTime;
      //percent.innerHTML = x.currentTime;
      slider.max = x.duration;
      keys();
})

function sToTime(t) {
  return padZero(parseInt((t / (60 * 60)) % 24)) + ":" +
         padZero(parseInt((t / (60)) % 60)) + ":" + 
         padZero(parseInt((t) % 60));
}
function padZero(v) {
  return (v < 10) ? "0" + v : v;
}
```

So in **main.js** I have the “brains” i guess, of the entire player. The function **PlayAlbum(clicked_id)** is the problem. That’s the function that is supposed to filter all the songs so that the only songs left are the ones from the clicked album.

**song-list.js**

So in **song-list.js** i just have the list of songs and the album art for it. I also have the link to the file. For you guys’s Sake i really should organize this better, but that’ll happen in a little bit. I didn’t include the code in here because its not an important factor to my problem.

**variables.js**

```
var AlbumName = {
  1 : "",
  2 : "",
  3 : "",
  4 : "",
  5 : "Mania",
  6 : "",
  7 : "",
  8 : "",
  9 : "American Beauty/American Psycho",
  10 : "",
  11 : "Vessel",
  12 : "",
  13 : "Vessel",
  14 : "American Beauty/American Psycho",
  15 : "",
  16 : "",
  17 : "",
  18 : "",
  19 : "",
  20 : "",
  21 : "",
  22 : "",
  23 : "Vessel",
  24 : "",
  25 : "",
  26 : "",
  27 : "",
  28 : "",
  29 : "",
  30 : "",
  31 : "",
  32 : "",
  33 : "Mania",
  34 : "Watching the Sky",
  35 : "",
  36 : "",
  37 : ""
}

var AlbumIMG = {
  1 : "",
  2 : "",
  3 : "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/monstercat/images/0/0c/Marshmello_-_Alone.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160513204533",
  4 : "",
  5 : "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41K3SuHNQpL._SS500.jpg",
  6 : "",
  7 : "",
  8 : "",
  9 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b6/American_Beauty_American_Psycho_cover.png",
  10 : "",
  11 : "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41%2BCuqqyyvL.jpg",
  12 : "",
  13 : "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41%2BCuqqyyvL.jpg",
  14 : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b6/American_Beauty_American_Psycho_cover.png",
  15 : "",
  16 : "",
  17 : "",
  18 : "",
  19 : "",
  20 : "",
  21 : "",
  22 : "",
  23 : "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41%2BCuqqyyvL.jpg",
  24 : "",
  25 : "",
  26 : "",
  27 : "",
  28 : "",
  29 : "",
  30 : "",
  31 : "",
  32 : "",
  33 : "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41K3SuHNQpL._SS500.jpg",
  34 : "https://iplock.weebly.com/uploads/9/5/7/3/95731436/p184.png",
  35 : "",
  36 : "",
  37 : ""
}
```

So the **variables.js** file is just the list of the albums, like the first set of variables is the list of songs and what album they belong to. The second is the links to the album art for the specified album.

To see my full code go to https://github.com/lightning417techa/Music

**EDIT 2**

I was thinking about simplifying this a bit but i came to a point where if i did simplify the creation of the song buttons and the album buttons, it throws an error. I also noticed that i cant set the ids as a number.

Comment: Could you please reduce your code to a  version only showcasing the issue. It's quiet hard to read like this. Also I would not recomment posting any api keys in here.

Comment: Yeah i just realized that,

Comment: This code is very difficult to understand, looks like hundreds of lines (Didn't count them BTW). But the one thing that I don't understand is the structure. Why not creating an array of album objects with same structure (Like `{'AlbumName': 'Mania', 'AlbumIMG': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/...', 'SongsList': [<array_of_song_objects_here>]}`). You can also use array related [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to filter for the correct album/song ans so on.. So this code could be simplified a lot

Comment: Wait, so yes i do know that it could be simplified but I don’t really know how. And so could i create an array like    var songs =  { song : [“stuff”, “stuff”, “stuff”,], song2 : [“stuff”, “stuff”, “stuff”]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `let AB = document.getElementById(AN);` is your issue. Throw a `debugger` in after that line and make sure it's populating the way you expect it to. I'm fairly certain that ids can't be numbers and you're expecting them to be (if I'm reading this all correctly).

Comment: I did notice that, i will keep that in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So i went old school and actually grabbed a whiteboard and wrote my idea down. I came to realization that in the function `StartUI()` it sets The I’d of the button to a number, then i read the documentation on w3schools and i saw that i can remove part of a string for example if i did `document.getElementById(“Text”).innerHTML = MyEditedText;` would turn out to

```
let myText = "hello1";
document.getElementById(“Text”).innerHTML = myText;
function MyFunction() {
  let MyEditedText = myText.replace("hello", "");
  document.getElementById(“Text”).innerHTML = MyEditedText;
}
```

```
<p id=“Text”></p>
<button onclick=“MyFunction”>Click Me</button>
```